# How to log in and accept consent using Keycloak with a custom login page

Tags: reactjs, authentication, keycloak

I'm trying to use Keycloak to handle user login and consent. Once he's logged in, he will receive an SMS with a code, then he has to give his consent to let another application use his information.

All of that works fine with Keycloak's default login page. But I'm trying to use our own login page.

When calling protocol/openid-connect/auth, all I receive is the form.
And I can't access the token, getting a "client consent required" error.

Does someone know if it's possible? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing this issue also if we disable client consent require how to create custom consent page where's consent api?